# Using ROM-SQL or Sequel, how can I query for multiple records using multiple columns (with different values per row)?

Tags: sql, sequel, rom-rb, rom-sql

Given a database table with these three rows:

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| John | Doe |
| Will | Smith |
| John | Smith |

Note: I specifically left out the `id` here because we might be dealing with a case where either we don't have the `id` or maybe `[first_name, last_name]` is the composite primary key.

### **How do I retrieve John Doe and Will Smith without also retrieving John Smith in one database round-trip?**

**We can do it for one record:**

1. We can use the `rom-sql` `by_pk` method to retrieve one record by composite primary keys (if this happens to be a composite primary key).

```rb
users.by_pk('John', 'Doe')
```

2. We can use `where` (from pretty much any database adapter) to retrieve the record

```rb
users.where(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe')`
```

---

**But how do we do the same for multiple records?**

(1) doesn't work (or at least I don't know the syntax). Please enlighten me if you do!

The trivial way is to just run a map in Ruby and retrieve it:

```rb
array_of_first_names_and_last_names.map do |first_name_and_last_name|
  first_name, last_name = first_name_and_last_name
  users.by_pk(first_name, last_name)
end
```

We can do the same trivial map in Ruby for (2).

**But how can we do it in one database round-trip?**

(2) does not work because I will accidentally retrieve John Smith as well if I just do this:

```rb
users.where(first_name: ['John', 'Will'], last_name: ['Doe', 'Smith'])
```

### Describe what you’ve tried

I've tried to do this in Sequel (and you can do it in SQL as well if you wanted):

```rb
def find_all_by_pk(array_of_first_names_and_last_names:) # [['John', 'Doe'], ['Will', 'Smith']]
  dataset = users.dataset
  array_of_first_names_and_last_names.each.with_index do |first_name_and_last_name, index|
    first_name, last_name = first_name_and_last_name
    index += 1
    dataset = if index == 1
                dataset.where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
              else
                dataset.or(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
              end
  end
  dataset.to_a
end
```

UPDATE: A few months later (17th Nov 2022), I stumbled upon my own question while trying to solve a similar problem. All I managed to do was make the Ruby part of it a bit cleaner:

```rb
def find_all_by_pk(array_of_first_names_and_last_names:) # [['John', 'Doe'], ['Will', 'Smith']]
  head, *tail = array_of_first_names_and_last_names
  initial_query = users.dataset.where(first_name: head[0], last_name: head[1])
  tail.reduce(initial_query) do |query, first_name_and_last_name|
    first_name, last_name = first_name_and_last_name
    query.or(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
  end.to_a
end
```

Is there a better/cleaner/more idiomatic way to do this?